# Error Error initializing classpath: Plugin with id 'org.grails.plugins.views-json' not found

Tags: gradle, grails

I am working with Grails 3.3.11 and Java 1.8.0_275 (open).

All of a sudden my project stopped working. When I run grails clean, or run-app it says:

```
 * Where:
Build file '/media/alfredo/1TBHDD/CMB/Code projects/Grails 3/plataforma-mserp/build.gradle' line: 22

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'cmberp'.
> Plugin with id 'org.grails.plugins.views-json' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

CONFIGURE FAILED

Total time: 1.121 secs
| Error Error initializing classpath: Plugin with id 'org.grails.plugins.views-json' not found. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Here is my build.gradle file. It indicates an error in the lines 22 and 72. I don't know why it is happening because it was working as expected. Maybe some configuration. The only thing I added to this project was jgit-flow configuration.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath files('gradle/gradle-trust-all.jar')
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:${gormVersion-".RELEASE"}"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:1.2.9"
        classpath 'io.github.robwin:jgitflow-gradle-plugin:0.6.0'
    }
}

version "$version"
group "br.gov.cmb"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.plugins.views-json"
apply plugin: 'io.github.robwin.jgitflow'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:events"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.16.Final"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json-templates"
    compile "com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc" //Added by cmb developer
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.13' //Added by cmb developer
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:rest-api"
    runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb:1.1.2"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
}


bootRun {
    jvmArgs('-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always')
    addResources = true
    String springProfilesActive = 'spring.profiles.active'
    systemProperty springProfilesActive, System.getProperty(springProfilesActive)
}


tasks.withType(Test) {
    systemProperty "geb.env", System.getProperty('geb.env')
    systemProperty "geb.build.reportsDir", reporting.file("geb/integrationTest")
    systemProperty "webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver')
    systemProperty "webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty('webdriver.gecko.driver')
}
```

Please help me!

Thanks.

Alfredo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to a repository outage that is in progress right now.  See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11825.

Comment: Perfect. Working now as expected. Thank you!