# Grails 4 https://repo.grails.org/grails/core no longer able to download dependencies

Tags: gradle, grails, build.gradle, grails-plugin, grails-4

We have been using Grails 4.0.0 for more than a year now and starting yesterday, we are now unable to download dependencies with the below build config.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
}
```

}

and we are getting the below error. it looks like https://repo.grails.org/grails/core is no longer the correct URL repo to download dependencies. Does any know the correct URL or how can this be resolved? Have tried http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/ and tried different kind of stuff but didn't work. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'IronDataMobile_2.11.9'.
```

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:4.0.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-gradle-plugin/4.0.0/grails-gradle-plugin-4.0.0.pom
> - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-gradle-plugin/4.0.0/grails-gradle-plugin-4.0.0.jar
> Required by:
> project :

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error Error initializing classpath: Plugin with id 'org.grails.plugins.views-json' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67873128/error-error-initializing-classpath-plugin-with-id-org-grails-plugins-views-jso)

Answer (score 1):

The 'grails-core' repository does not exist in the listed repositories: https://repo.grails.org/ui/repos/tree/General/

However, 'core' does exist which includes [`org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin`](https://repo.grails.org/artifactory/core/org/grails/grails-gradle-plugin/)

So update the repository:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/artifactory/core/" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ivar's comment has much more information than my answer.

Comment: As a reminder: this is a temporary URL change and is not intended to be permanent.  Status updates here: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11825