# Why is Grails completely broken since Sunday and why is no one noticing?

Tags: grails

Since Sunday, I and my co-worker cannot build any Grails project nor even create a new Grails app of any version. We have completely independent development environments.

For example:

> $ grails create-app --profile web junk
> | Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: Could not find artifact org.grails:grails-bom:pom:4.0.10 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/core) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

`./gradlew dependencies` also fails with `Could not find org.grails:grails-gradle-model:3.2.13)`.

The repository repo.grails.org is up, but when I browse it, it is very slow and missing many, many artifacts.

Is their a way to configure `build.gradle` to fix this?  We have several Grails projects using different versions, mostly using the default repository configuration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error Error initializing classpath: Plugin with id 'org.grails.plugins.views-json' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67873128/error-error-initializing-classpath-plugin-with-id-org-grails-plugins-views-jso)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually been some discussion here on stackoverflow, but more on a github issue: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11825

You can certainly read that issue for far more info than makes sense to post here, but the short version is: URL changed unintentionally, temporary workaround is to move to `https://repo.grails.org/artifactory/core`

Comment: It gets further, then still somehow searches for an artifact (grails/core/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging) in the old place, even tho I used installed gradle instead of gradlew (which has the old url embedded).  I'll just wait for jFrog to fix it.   I am unhappy that artif*ctory is a single point of failure.

Comment: Yeah, this has definitely made me wonder where a repo mirror may be, or if one even exists.

Answer (score 0):

I guess we have an official message related to this issue in grails blog - https://grails.org/blog/2021-06-10-grails-wrapper-update.html